# Solve for x in log question?

Tags: logarithms

If $2^x$ (2 to the power of x) $= 100$, what is $x$?

I got $100/\log2$. Is that correct? I know how I solved it but now I don't get how I did and why I did what I did.

The choices were...

$$2 / \log2;$$
$$10 / \log2 ; $$
$$50 / \log2 ; $$
$$100 / \log2 ; $$

Comment: I don't know what base you are using for the log. If it is $10$, then from $2^x=100$ we get by taking logs that $x\log_{10}2=2$.

Comment: By definition of the logarithm, it is the logarithm (base 2) of 100, or by change of base formula, an option would be $\frac{ln100}{ln2}$

Comment: think about what log(100) is

Answer (score 1):

The answer should be $2/\log 2$.

$$\begin{align}
2^x & =100\\
\log 2^x & =\log 100\\
x\log 2 & = 2\\
x &=\frac2{\log 2}
\end{align}$$

Remember that $\log x$ answers the question "What power of 10 is x?"  So, $\log100=2$
Also a useful propery of $\log$ is $\log x^a=a\log x$. This explains how I got the third line.

Answer (score 0):

No that is wrong. The solution should be $\frac{\log(100)}{\log(2)}$.

To calculate the log of x to the basis b you can use this formula:

$$ \log_b(x) = \frac{\log(x)}{\log(b)} $$

Answer (score 0):

By definition, $2^{^2log(a)}=a$. Applying this to $a=100$ results in $2^x=2^{^2log(100)}$, thus $x=^2log(100)$. This can also be written as $x=\frac{log(100)}{log(2)}$. Notice that $log(100)=2$, thus $x=\frac{2}{log(2)}$

Comment: Notice that $log(100)=2$, thus $x=\frac{2}{log(2)}$